# Login with Enums

Tags: swift, enums

I'm trying to create a simple way of logging in users, however it does not seem to work at the moment. I keep getting and error with a missing argument in `.Email(LoginUser)`

```
enum LoginProvider {
    case Facebook
    case Email(String, String)

    func login() {
        switch self {
        case .Email(LoginUser) where LoginUser.isValid():
            break

        case .Facebook:

            break
        }
    }

}

struct LoginUser {
    let email: String
    let password: String
    func isValid() -> Bool {
        return email != "" && password != ""
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code on playground and made some changes that would fix the errors. Which are 1. `case Email(LoginUser)` and 2. missing `default:` case in `LoginProvider`'s `login()`.

You make these changes and I believe it would fix the issue.
Here is the working code on playgrund.

```
struct LoginUser {

    let email: String
    let password: String

    func isValid() -> Bool {
        return email.characters.count > 0 && password.characters.count > 0
    }
}

enum LoginProvider {

    case Facebook
    case Email(LoginUser)

    func login() {

        switch self {

        case .Email(let user) where user.isValid():
            print("Login with email")
            break

        case .Facebook:
            print("Login with Facebook")
            break

        default:
            break
        }

    }
}


let provider: LoginProvider = LoginProvider.Email(LoginUser(email: "email", password: "pass"))
provider.login()
```

Comment: I would also suggest to use email.characters.count over email != ""  :)

Answer (score 1):

You've made a couple mistakes in your code, here's the fixed version:

```
enum LoginProvider {
    case Facebook
    case Email(LoginUser) // note that LoginUser is used as Type here

    func login() {
        switch self {

        // And here, loginUser is an instance of type LoginUser
        case .Email(let loginUser) where loginUser.isValid():
            break

        case .Email(let loginUser):
            // Switch has to be exhaustive, 
            // in this case you should handle invalid user
            break

        case .Facebook:
            break
        }
    }

}

struct LoginUser {
    let email: String
    let password: String
    func isValid() -> Bool {
        return !email.isEmpty && !password.isEmpty
    }
}
```

I'd also suggest you check the chapter on Associated Values in [Apple's Swift book](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html).

Comment: The `switch` here will need at least one other case to make it exhaustive.